# What is the design pattern for plugins (and their managers) called?

Tags: 9

I am trying to figure out how to design (and subsequently implement) as plugin-like solution in Symfony.
I found this article https://drupalize.me/tutorial/what-are-plugins?p=2766 that says:

> Plugins are a general reusable solution to a recurring problem within a given context... we call this a design pattern. This one just happens to be specific to Drupal.

Looking for a definition and/or links to similar design patterns.

Comment: The Site Audit module defines its own SiteAuditCheck and SiteAuditReport plugin. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/site_audit/-/tree/8.x-3.x/src/Plugin. Other module's maintainers can then add their own checks from their modules.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. I am asking for information about the design pattern behind the plugin system.

Comment: `I am trying to figure out how to design (and subsequently implement) as plugin-like solution` – Just look how other modules do it I'd say.

Comment: I want to implement that pattern in Symfony (or any other non-Drupal framework), that is why I want to know what it is called, if it goes by a name.

Comment: Ah, so you are asking: Hey there's that plugin system in Drupal and I'm wondering what exactly is the design pattern behind it and how someone would implement a similar approach in other frameworks?

Comment: Yes, not really interested in the implementation details yet. First wanna make sure I know what that thingy is built after. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure it really has a name - _Factory pattern with discoverability_ maybe?

Comment: Haha! That kid must have a parent or more. :-)
Most probably originally inspired by ctools, right?
I like the Discoverable-Plugin-Factory wording.

Comment: +Configurable? Discoverable-Configurable-Plugin-Factory. First a plugin class is discovered, then configured and finally instantiated through a factory method.